# How are “il faut” and “we” related?

Tags: sens, anglais, sujet, pronoms-impersonnels

As part of A1.1 level French language training, my teacher introduced the following sentence:

> Il faut faire quel exercice ?

and translated it into English as:

> Which exercise should we do?

I know that *il* maps to *it* and *quel* maps to *what*.

My question: If I map the words from the French statement to the English statement, I do not understand the meaning of *faut*, *faire*, *il* and *quel*. How are these two sentences related?

Comment: a more literal translation would be "what exercise must be done?"

Comment: Part of the problem comes from the "mapping" process. When translating, the smallest meaningful unit should be the sentence.

Comment: As a side remark, I regret that the French sentence is not using the interrogative form : "Quel exercice faut-il faire ?". Even though this form tends to disappear, I would hope for a French course to use a correct (and more formal) gramatical form, especially in written language...

Comment: @Bartdude Don't you think people learning a language would aim to speak it like actual people rather than books? When French courses impose formal French on students (which is the case most of the time), they have a hard time getting understood in conversation and/or sound funny : « Où la gare se trouve-t-elle ? »...

Comment: @GAMPUB > I totally agree with that, but I actually also regret the disparition of the interrogative form in usual language. "Où est la gare ?" sounds better as "La gares est où ?".  for example, while not being that formal... so in some case the interrogative form makes more sense than others. For someone learning a language, I also find it easier to refer to grammatical rules to identify the different parts of a sentence. Maybe the use of interrogative form in the present example would have helped the OP as the order would have been closer to the English translation

Comment: language localisation is creating barriers. Why can't Europe accept English. We asians have accepted for our own good.

Answer (score 5):

*Faut* and *faire* here correspond to *should* and *do*. You are mistaken that *quel* translates *what* (the correct pronoun is usually *que* or *quoi*). It in fact corresponds to *which*.

*Il* here serves as a **dummy subject**, because *falloir* is an impersonal verb in french. It gives you trouble because although the English sentence is an accurate and idiomatic translation, the literal french form (which is grammatical, but seen as very stilted because contemporary spoken french avoids using *nous*) would be *Quel exercice devons-nous faire?*.

Comment: "Quelle EST votre profession?" In this question, "quelle" translates to "what". So, how come in the above answer "quel" is "which"? Similarly, "c'est a quelle page?" What is "quelle" here? This is very confusing!!!

Comment: @overexchange Might not be as confusing if you consider "which" to be defined as "being **what** one or ones out of a group"? Then *quel* can kiiiind of always be "what".

Comment: @Circeus To make your already great answer even clearer, maybe you could tell that an impersonal  sentence is somehow a passive structure, which would probably not be translated as such (every proofreader I use blames me each time a passive structure is found).

Comment: @overexchange You should open a thread for this, because it could interest many people. I replied to your "which/what" translation question in my answer, because here, there's no room.

Answer (score 0):

"Il faut" is a whole expression, you have to use it as a whole.
The *il* is the impersonal form. It's not always *it*, it can be *one* sometimes.

An equivalent could be "On doit" (translated in English by "one should", "one must" depending on the sentence).

*Il faut faire un exercice* = *We have to do an exercise*. *We must do an exercise.*
In French, it will be the same "il faut" for an advice and for a strong obligation.

So "Quel exercice faut-il faire/doit-on faire ?" (the more formal and correct form) or "Quel exercice il faut faire ?", etc, are constructed with "Quel exercice" + the whole "il faut" or "faut-il" expression.

Examples:

> Faut-il faire l'exercice de math ?
>   Doit-on faire tous les exercices de la page ?
>   Dois-je faire...
>   Devons-nous faire...

All these forms are formal.

Informal:

> On doit apprendre cette leçon ?
>   Est-ce qu'on doit faire les exercices ?

*Il faut faire quel exercice ?* and *Quel exercice il faut faire ?* are the same but the first one is very informal.

---

Second question:

*Quel* translate to *what* OR *which*, depending on the sentence.

- *Which exercise should we do?* = *Quel exercice devons nous faire ?*

Because *lequel* is only used when you have a clear choice:

- *Je prends un crayon sur la table. Lequel ?* (which one?).

*Lequel* is NEVER a question word. So, it's easy when you have *which* in a question, it's always *quel*.

To know how to translate,

- ask yourself whether there is a clear choice between several things.
- and whether it's a question word.