# Étymologie de « il faut »

Tags: étymologie

> [[Wiktionary.org]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/falloir): Du latin *fallere* (« faillir ») d’après la troisième personne [faut](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faut) (latin [fallit](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fallit)) sur le modèle de [valoir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/valoir), de [valere](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/valeo#la).

J'aimerais approfondir la définition, que je comprends déjà  et dont je ne m’enquiers pas.

1. Comment *il* et *falloir* se sont-ils combinés pour signifier « il est nécessaire » ?
   Je sais déjà que [*il* est un 'dummy pronoun'](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13720/1995).
2. Pourquoi est-ce que « falloir » est un [verbe impersonnel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_impersonnel) ?   Comment l'était-il devenu ?
   Comment ***falloir*** n'a-t-il pas évolué en un verbe personnel  ?

SVP, veuillez dévoiler et expliquer tous les changements sémantiques dissimulés et manquants.  Comment interpréter cette étymologie pour comprendre comment les sauts sémantiques se sont écartés du sens littéral et du sens du latin ?

Comment: Quel est le "sens littéral original", le sens latin ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Oui, merci.

Comment: L'équivalent personnel de falloir est devoir: _il faut que je_ => _je dois_

Comment: Il y a beaucoup d'explications ici, et notamment des références sur son usage impersonnel: http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=1286834295;

Answer (score 2):

Il me semble que [faillir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faillir) est une bonne clef pour faire le lien entre *fallit* et *faut*. D'ailleurs :

> De l’ancien français [faillir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faillir#fro), du latin vulgaire [*fallire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fallire) lui-même issu du latin classique [*fallere*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fallere#la) (« tromper »).
>   → voir [falloir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/falloir), issu du même mot.

On peut esquisser un tel cheminement (avec `*-` sur les étapes imaginées) :

> 3- *fallere fidem* : manquer à son serment. ([fallo](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fallo))
>   *- Il faillit à son serment.
>   2- Faillir à son devoir. ([faillir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faillir))
>   *- Il fallait qu'il fasse son devoir.
>   *- Il faut qu'il fasse son devoir.
>   1- Être de nécessité, de devoir, d’obligation, de bienséance. ([falloir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/falloir))

En espagnol, on dit [*fallar*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fallar#es) (pour *manquer* - *faillir*).

Comment: Une hypothèse plus simple est que s'il faut que je réalise une tâche, c'est bien que tant qu'elle n'est pas réalisée je faillis à sa réalisation.

Comment: @mouviciel: Pour le passage de *faillir* à *falloir*, je suis d'accord, mais en quoi est-ce plus simple que ce que je propose ?

Comment: Plus simple n'est pas le mot. Je devrais plutôt dire plus court.

Answer (score -1):

Faillir vient d'un patois local (normand) imprégné de grand-bretagne qui, comme chacun le sait, est dirigé par deux grandes règles : "be able to" et "i have to".
il faut = je dois = c'est mon devoir = faire = agir = que je le fasse pour mon salut = je suis donc digne d'être votre serviteur ; il s'agit donc d'un principe suzerain basant les lignes directrices de la civilisation par un élan salvateur et créateur.
Il n'y a donc pas de négatif, d'échec, car si l'on n'est pas capable, on n'est ni un homme ni libre et donc sans avenir.
Faux amis : Aucun rapport avec le latin, et le sens de "échouer" même si un verbe identique ou une locution étrangère peuvent être employées; ce sont des origines distinctes qui en déterminent le sens.

Comment: Quelles sont les sources?